# Why a 'resolve' directing dose not work in webpack.cofig.js

Tags: node.js, npm, bundler, package.json

Cannot understand, why the program keep looking for .src? while trying to test resolve method on the webpack.config.js file. As I understood, after 'npm run build' the 'resolve' make a new folder and file by following the pre-setting. please help pool Novice. thank you.

```
const path = require('path')

// export

module.export ={
  entry:'./js/main.js',
  output:{
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename:'main.js'
  }
}
```

and error showed as below

```
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/MU/Desktop/webpack-template-basic'
resolve './src' in '/Users/MU/Desktop/webpack-template-basic'
  using description file: /Users/MU/Desktop/webpack-template-basic/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/MU/Desktop/webpack-template-basic/package.json (relative path: ./src)
      no extension
```

![error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfFo4.png

Answer (score -1):

After spending couple of hours to search for solving the problem, I just created 'src' folder in the project folder. it was works but still has ongoing problem. Someone has same problem as me just creating folder as you see on the error. It is temporary solve not for the original solution. best wish you who start coding like me. Thanks.

- and had stupid mistake that i typed in cli 'npm run dev' instead of 'npm run build'. the folder and file created when run the production. not open dev-server.